# I can't get position attribute off a bufferGeometry

Tags: javascript, three.js, buffer-geometry

I've got a line "walking around my scene" (some kind of a 3D snake) randomly and the next thing I wish to achieve is set a box around its head.
The line `bufferGeometry` is set by

```
        var positions1 = new Float32Array( MAX_POINTS * 3 ); // 3 vertices per point
        var positions2 = new Float32Array( MAX_POINTS * 3 ); // 3 vertices per point
        buffGeometry1.addAttribute( 'position', new THREE.BufferAttribute( positions1, 3 ) );
        buffGeometry2.addAttribute( 'position', new THREE.BufferAttribute( positions2, 3 ) );
```

I chose to set a cube (`boxGeometry` object) around it, and I used the following code lines to try and achieve that:

```
            var positioning = buffGeometry1.getAttribute('position');
            cube.position.x = positioning[0];//(line1.geometry.attributes.position.array[drawCount]);
            cube.position.y = positioning[1];//(line1.geometry.attributes.position.array[drawCount + 1]);
            cube.position.z = positioning[2];
```

As I debug, I see that my `positioning` array is undefined. so I guess something there went wrong.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
console.log(buffGeometry1.getAttribute('position'))
```

My THREE.BufferGeometry shows me that verticles are stored in positioning.array so you should acces them by:

```
positioning.array[0]
positioning.array[1]
positioning.array[2]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you add let's say a point to your scene using BufferGeometry, you can also try accessing the coordinates like this :

```
/// X coordinate /////      
console.log(point1.geometry.attributes.position.array[0]); 
/// Y coordinate /////   
console.log(point1.geometry.attributes.position.array[1]);  
/// Z coordinate /////           
console.log(point1.geometry.attributes.position.array[2]);
```